# Combo Identity: How to prove this using Induction

Tags: combinatorics

> $$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \binom{n + k}{k}x^n = \dfrac{1}{(1 - x)^{k + 1}} $$

Could someone suggest how I should get started to prove this using induction?

Comment: How to get started? The base case I would suggest: $k=0$

Comment: The series you are asking about can be found by taking derivatives of the geometric series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = (1-x)^{-1}$$

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Welcome to M.SE! When you post a question, please try to show some of your work, give some context for the problem, and explain where you are confused. The way you have stated this particular inquiry, other users have no idea if you have given the problem any thought on your own. With a little extra data, your questions will be better-received, and you will be more likely to get helpful and personalized answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need proof by induction here? Use the Binomial Theorem! Simply set $-k-1 = v$:
$$
(1-x)^{v} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{v}{j}(-x)^j
$$
Now use the property of the binomial coefficient: $\binom{v}{j} = v (v-1) \ldots (v-j+1)\cdot \frac{1}{j!}$ Now use the definition for $v$: $\binom{-k-1}{j} = (-1)^j \frac{(k+1)(k+2) \ldots (k+j-1)}{j!} = (-1)^j =\frac{(k+j-1)!}{k! j!} = \frac{
(-1)^j}{k} \binom{k+j-1}{j}$. The $(-1)^j$ term cancels out, and the expression becomes what you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac1{(1-x)^{m+1}}=\frac{1-x}{(1-x)^{m+2}}=\frac1{(1-x)^{m+2}}-\frac x{(1-x)^{m+2}}$$

$$\implies(1-x)^{-(m+1)}=(1-x)^{-(m+2)}-x(1-x)^{-(m+2)}$$

Assume that the formula is true for $k=m+2$ and establish the same for $k=m+1$

---

Alternatively, use  $$(1-x)(1-x)^{-(m+2)}=(1-x)^{-(m+1)}$$

Assume that the formula is true for $k=m+1$ and establish the same for $k=m+2$

Answer (score 1):

You start like that:
For $k=0$: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{n} x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} \checkmark$$

Then,we suppose that: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$

For $k+1$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k+1}{k+1} x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n+k+1}{k+1} \binom{n+k}{k}x^n$$

then you have to continue,in order to find a relation that stands.